# what is out in System.out.println()

Tags: java, outputstream

In the following statements, if `System` is a class and `println()` and `print()` are methods, then what is `out`?

```
System.out.print();
System.out.println();
```

I cannot understand the hierarchy. As in simple I have never used anything between class name and method name.

Comment: JDK is your friend

Comment: In eclipse, press ``Ctrl`` and CLICK on ``out`` ..... hope get your answer.

Comment: i am beginner and not using eclipse but i got my answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

out is a public static instance of the PrintStream class. println() and print() are methods of PrintStream class

Answer (score 1):

out is a static member field of System class and is of type PrintStream.

Answer (score 1):

out is a static field of the System class. It is of type PrintStream which has a method println().

Answer (score 0):

`System` is a final class which is present in java.lang package. `out` is the reference of PrintStream class and a static member of System class.

[image]